# how can I make my copy constructor for doubly linked stack work

Tags: c++, stack, copy-constructor

Hi there I have this copy constructor and it looks like it is not making proper copies and throwing an error. The error is: "Running main() from gtest_main.cc
 Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
" . I'm testing this constructor with google gtest.  headPtr // Pointer to first node in the chain; and topPtr // Pointer to last node in the chain;

template
DLinkedStack::DLinkedStack(const DLinkedStack &aStack) {

```
//Points to nodes in orignal chain
    Node<T> *origChainPtr = aStack.headPtr;
    if (origChainPtr == nullptr)
        headPtr = topPtr = nullptr;    // Original bag is empty
    else {

        // Copy first Node
        headPtr = new Node<T>();
        headPtr->setItem(origChainPtr->getItem());

        //Point to first node in new chain
        Node<T> *newChainPtr = headPtr;
        //Point to last node in new chain
        Node<T> *otherChainPtr = topPtr;

        //copy remaining nodes
        while (origChainPtr != nullptr) {
            // Advance original chain pointer
            origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();

            // get next item from original chain
            T nextItem = origChainPtr->getItem();

             //get previous item from original chain
            T prevItem = origChainPtr->getItem();

            // create a new node contaning the next item
            Node<T> *newNodePtr = new Node<T>(nextItem);

            // create a new node contaning the prev item
            Node<T> *newNodePtr1 = new Node<T>(prevItem);

            //Link new node to the end of new chain
            newChainPtr->setNext((newNodePtr));

            //Link new node1 to the begining of new chain
            newChainPtr->setPrev(newNodePtr1);


            // advance pointer to new last node
            newChainPtr = newChainPtr->getNext();

            // advance one forward
            otherChainPtr = otherChainPtr->getNext();

        }
        newChainPtr->setNext(nullptr);    // Flag end of chain
    }
}
```

Comment: While this comment might appear a little off side.. If you learn C++, instead of writing basic data structures like double linked lists first, why not first learn how to use those already there? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list The benefit I see with first using the data structures before implementing them yourself is, that you get a good idea of common list operations and their names. And as it is template code, you can always inspect how e.g. ``std::list<>`` is implemented.

Comment: @BitTickler thanks that page looks helpful. I'll take a look at it. I'm new to C++, been studying Java for few semesters, but had to take data structure in C++ this semester.

Comment: Another tip. Now, you are stuck with a problem in your code, it is a good opportunity to learn how to use your debugger. Trying to program C/C++ without a convenient debugger at hand is not really productive. Anyone who says otherwise also tells tales about catching 2 whales before breakfeast every other day ... with bare hands... ;)